# Maximum length of CQL query string

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

Is there a maximum length limitation the cql query string?

I am planning to execute a long query of this form: `select * from table where key in ('abc', 'xyz', ...)` and I am estimating the length of the query string to be about 60kB in worst cases.

Comment: As Alex pointed out, the length of the query string won't be as much of a problem as 60K worth of `IN` parameters.  That's called a "multi-key query" and is a known anti-pattern in Cassandra.  The reason it's so bad, is that it will have to choose a coordinator (regardless of which LoadBalancingPolicy you use) and that coordinator will have to hit every node in the cluster to satisfy this query.  Pro-tip: Keep your number of `IN` parameters to something you can count on one hand.

Comment: If my previous comment wasn't convincing enough, I'll add that questions like this are the ones which end up being a part of Cassandra conference presentations under the heading of "**Don't do this**."

Answer (score 4):

Per [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/refLimits.html), you have a limit on a number of parameters in query (65535), but not the string length.

But you need carefully consider your approach - have a few values in the `IN` is ok, but having too many of them will lead to troubles because the node that receives your request ("coordinator") will need to forward queries to all nodes that have data for your keys, wait for results, collect everything into one piece, and send back.  Most probable, this will lead to overload of the coordinator node, and either crashing, or time outing, or something else.

If you issue your requests in parallel, by using the asynchronous API, then you can get better performance comparing to using `IN`.

Answer (score 3):

In testing, I was able to get to a query length of about 90K before the system started throwing errors.

Depending on how you're doing your reads, you may run into an error of "Argument list too long" way before you get to 65535 items in your list. I was able to reproduce this with a list of just 5000 (using a list of IDs created via `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid`).